# convert cell array in matlab to list in R

Tags: r, matlab

I am converting a Cell arrays into R.
In MATLAB I use x=cell(10,n).I want and assign a matrix to each cell in a loop like:

```
for i in 1:10
for j in 1:n
x(i,j) = [i*ones(len,1), ones(len,j)]
```

n here is like number of columns.
How do I do this in R? 
I tried List in R, I guess this x looks like contains 10 lists and each list has n sub-list  and each sub-list has a matrix. Is this correct?

The pic show  the first loop generated in Matlab .n=7. The 1st row contains one numeric matrix in each cell.
what i want to get is able to get the the 1st matrix"3x10 double" by using

```
x[1][1] in R
```

Refence [how to calculate the mean of list of list of matrices in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440904/how-to-calculate-the-mean-of-list-of-list-of-matrices-in-r)

[image: This is from Matlab]

Answer: according to the link above the code is something like:

```
x<-NULL
for (i in 1:10){
   test<-NULL
for (j in 1:n){
      test[[j]]<-matrix
    }
x[[i]]<-test
}
```

Comment: This is really confusing. What exactly do you want as an output?

Comment: Where is that picture from? Is that matlab code? R doesn't have cell arrays. You cannot store a matrix inside a normal matrix. You could create a list-matrix but those aren't always easy to work with.

Comment: @MrFlick YES, it is a matlab code I wrote. Any better suggestion? Does x = vector(’list’,n) make sense?

Comment: You can store matrices inside a list, with matrix-like dimensions: `matrix(list(matrix(1:3),matrix(2:4),matrix(3:5),matrix(4:6)),nrow=2)` As @MrFlick notes, it will be clunky to work with though.

Comment: Maybe add a comment to the code to indicate which languages. It's hard when you've tagged two. But like I said, R doesn't have cell-arrays. What do you plan to do with the data? Maybe there is a better way to do it in R

Comment: @thelatemail Can I get the matrix from x[1][1]

Comment: @Shawn88 - yep,  `x[1,1]` will do it.

Comment: @thelatemail,this does the job for me ! Thanks!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440904/how-to-calculate-the-mean-of-list-of-list-of-matrices-in-r

Answer (score 0):

```
x<-NULL
for (i in 1:10){
   test<-NULL
for (j in 1:n){
      test[[j]]<-matrix
    }
x[[i]]<-test
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, specify the number of rows and columns in your output, and define a function that returns the contents of each element in your output matrix.

```
n_rows <- 5
n_cols <- 7
get_element <- function(i, j)
{
  len <- 10
  cbind(rep.int(i, len), matrix(1, len, j))
}
```

We need to get all combinations of all the row and column values to pass to the function.

```
index <- arrayInd(seq_len(n_rows * n_cols), c(n_rows, n_cols))
```

Now we call get_element with each of these row/column pairs.

```
result <- mapply(get_element, index[, 1], index[, 2])
```

`result` is a list.  That means that it is a vector where each of the elements can contain different values.  To get what you want, you can set the dimensions of this list.

```
dim(result) <- c(n_rows, n_cols)

result
##      [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]       [,7]      
## [1,] Numeric,20 Numeric,30 Numeric,40 Numeric,50 Numeric,60 Numeric,70 Numeric,80
## [2,] Numeric,20 Numeric,30 Numeric,40 Numeric,50 Numeric,60 Numeric,70 Numeric,80
## [3,] Numeric,20 Numeric,30 Numeric,40 Numeric,50 Numeric,60 Numeric,70 Numeric,80
## [4,] Numeric,20 Numeric,30 Numeric,40 Numeric,50 Numeric,60 Numeric,70 Numeric,80
## [5,] Numeric,20 Numeric,30 Numeric,40 Numeric,50 Numeric,60 Numeric,70 Numeric,80
```

Individual matrices can be accessed with, for example, `result[[3, 5]]`.

```
result[[3, 5]]
##       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
##  [1,]    3    1    1    1    1    1
##  [2,]    3    1    1    1    1    1
##  [3,]    3    1    1    1    1    1
##  [4,]    3    1    1    1    1    1
##  [5,]    3    1    1    1    1    1
##  [6,]    3    1    1    1    1    1
##  [7,]    3    1    1    1    1    1
##  [8,]    3    1    1    1    1    1
##  [9,]    3    1    1    1    1    1
## [10,]    3    1    1    1    1    1
```

Note that while a list with dimensions is the nearest equivalent to a MATLAB cell array, it is a rarely used data structure.  This means that you won't be writing idiomatic R code with such a structure.  (One of the biggest mental transitions you have to make from coding in MATLAB to coding in R is to go from thinking in terms of matrices to thinking in terms of vectors.)

In this case, the obvious question is "why do you need to store all these matrices?".  It might be easier just to call `get_element` and retrieve the values as you need them.